# Request to see HaShem's vengeance

Tags: tefilla

In אבינו מלכנו, among other places, we ask HaShem, "נקום לעינינו נקמת דם עבדיך השפוך", which roughly translates to, "let us see You avenge the spilled blood of Your servants."

1) Why do we have a need to *witness* HaShem's vengeance on our enemies? Doesn't much of our faith tell us that it will happen, and isn't that good enough?

2) The rest of אבינו מלכנו is pretty peaceful (as are, if I'm not mistaken, most other prayer sets that make this or a similar request). Isn't this pretty much out of place?

Comment: In the Chabad nusach we omit the word לעינינו, so we are not asking to see G-d's revenge; only that it should happen.

Comment: @Michoel, in "_Av harachamim_" (after the _haftara_ on _Shabas_) also?

Comment: my guess is that "let us see" is equivalent to "within our days"

Comment: @msh210 In Av Harachamim (in Nusach Ashkenaz), the word l'eineinu appears twice. (" וְיִנְקום לְעֵינֵינוּ נִקְמַת דַּם עֲבָדָיו הַשָּׁפוּךְ") and ("יִוָּדַע בַּגּויִם לְעֵינֵינוּ נִקְמַת דַּם עֲבָדֶיךָ הַשָּׁפוּךְ"). Chabad omits the word from the first but not the second, which is a pasuk in Tehillim.

Comment: @HodofHod I have volunteered a new answer to your question about vengeance.

Answer (score 4):

This is based on the verse "Yivada' bagoyim l'eineinu nikmas dam avadecha hashafuch" (Tehillim 79:10), and is by no means innovated by the nusach. The Ibn Ezra writes that "before our eyes" means that we pray that we should survive to see HaShem's salvation of the Jewish people from our murderous enemies, and they should not have the opportunity to wipe us out first.

Answer (score 0):

[Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.79.10?lang=bi&with=Malbim&lang2=en) on the possuk in Tehillim points out that the request for vengeance is for the honour of His name and not for our personal vengeance.

> למה יאמרו הגוים איה נא אלהיהם ויש בזה חילול ה', אחר שהיית תמיד אלהי
>   ישענו, זאת שנית ראוי  שיודע בגוים לעינינו נקמת דם עבדיך השפוך,  שזה
>   ג''כ נוגע לכבוד שמך :
>
> Why do the nations say where then is their God and there is as a
>   result profanation of the Divine Name, seeing as you have always been
>   the G-d of our salvation. Therefore it is fitting that you should
>   demonstrate  to the nations in our view the vengeance of the blood of 
>   Your slain servants, since this also touches on the honour of Your
>   Name.

1] So, we want to witness the vengeance in order to witness the honour of His name in contrast to the profanation that took place before.

2] This prayer fits in with a number of other requests in two ways

a] acting for the sake of His Name and His martyrs:

עֲשֵׂה עִמָּנוּ לְמַעַן שְׁמֶךָ

עֲשֵׂה לְמַעַן הֲרוּגִים עַל שֵׁם קָדְשֶׁךָ

עֲשֵׂה לְמַעַן טְבוּחִים עַל יִחוּדֶךָ

עֲשֵׂה לְמַעַן בָּאֵי בָאֵשׁ וּבַמַּיִם עַל קִדּוּשׁ שְׁמֶךָ

and b] stopping the actions of our enemies:

בַּטֵּל מַחְשְׁבוֹת שׂוֹנְאֵינוּ

הָפֵר עֲצַת אוֹיְבֵינוּ

כַּלֵּה כָּל צַר וּמַשְׂטִין מֵעָלֵינוּ

סְתֹם פִּיּוֹת מַשְׂטִינֵינוּ וּמְקַטְרִיגֵנוּ

כַּלֵּה דֶבֶר וְחֶרֶב וְרָעָב וּשְׁבִי וּמַשְׁחִית וְעָוֹן וּשְׁמַד מִבְּנֵי בְרִיתֶךָ